# PhoneGap Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

Currently I am using an Ajax call to load a handlebar template from my local webserver into the application.

```
  $.ajax({
       url: "http://localhost/myTemplate.html",
       cache: true,
       success: function (data) {
           template = Handlebars.compile(data);
           $('#anyID').append(template);
       }
  });
```

Chrome on the Desktop does it fine, in contrast to my Android phone.

Is there a way to load the template correctly using PhoneGap?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please, can you inspect your device and share your console log?

Comment: GET http://localhost/myTemplate.html  jquery.js:9659

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling an absolute URL (`http://localhost/`). It works fine on your desktop, because it happens to be *also* your localhost, by chance.

But your phone is *not* your localhost. There is no web server running on your phone, so no localhost.

Use relative paths like `url : "myTemplate.html"`

Comment: I can't do that, because of this error:     XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Documents/myTemplate.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: You need to connect to a web server to test your page, not just open the "index.html" page in a browser. Connect to your localhost through your local network. For instance, on your phone, try reaching `http://192.168.1.100` (or whatever your desktop IP is), the page should show up.